# ThreadPool python multiprocessing error

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multithreading

I'm getting the following error while using ThreadPool in python, and I'm not sure what's going on...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 365, in <module>
    results=pool.map(my_func,my_list)
  File
  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
      File 
  "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multipro
cessing/pool.py", line 569, in get
            raise self._value
        TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

My code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool()

def my_func(num)

my_list = [one, two, three]
results=pool.map(my_func,my_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I even went to the /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multipro
cessing/pool.py file, and edited it to get more information. I put some prints there:

```
def get(self, timeout=None):
    self.wait(timeout)
    if not self._ready:
        raise TimeoutError
    print self._ready
    print  self._success
    print self._value
    if self._success:
        return self._value
    else:
        raise self._value
```

And this is what I got:

```
True
False
range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

So, am I doing something wrong? Is it a problem of the multithreading library? :?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. It is not because of the thread, but because something inside of my_func was returning that error, and the system thinks it is the problem of the thread.